# Write random numbers to an array of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I'm currently working on a simulator, which should imitate a certain business logic.
I try to create an object of a class `Suggestion` by picking two random strings out of two string arrays. The method should return an array of `Suggestion` objects. The array length is also variable. For now the returned array should be printed out in the console.

This is my class `Suggestion`:

```
 public class Suggestion
    {
        public Suggestion(string aktenName, string relevanz)
        {
            MAktenName = aktenName;
            MRelevanz = relevanz;
        }

        public string MAktenName { get; private set; }

        public string MRelevanz { get; private set; }
    }
```

My other class including the "logic" and the main method looks like this:

```
 private static void Main()
        {
            var test = GetSuggestions();

            for (var i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(test[i].MAktenName + "-" + test[i].MRelevanz + "%");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static Suggestion[] GetSuggestions()
        {
            var random = new Random();
            var suggestionsCount = random.Next(1, 10);
            var suggestions = new Suggestion[suggestionsCount];

            string[] names =
            {
                "721/12", "345/93", "478/54", "876/39", "546/27", "481/56", "824/39", "897/51",
                "574/48"
            };
            string[] relevance =
            {
                "10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90", "100"
            };

            for (var i = 0; i < suggestionsCount; i++)
            {
              
                var sugName = names[new Random().Next(0, names.Length)];
                var sugRelevance = relevance[new Random().Next(0, relevance.Length)];

                suggestions[i] = new Suggestion(sugName, sugRelevance);
            }
            return suggestions;
        }
```

My problem is that it prints out a random combination of the string arrays `sugName` and `sugRelevance` and it prints a variable amount of these, but all the objects of the class `Suggestions` are the same.
Like my result is something like:

> 345/93-20%
>
> 345/93-20%
>
> 345/93-20%
>
> 345/93-20%

I reckon it is something with the `new Random().Next(0, names.Length)` but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
var sugName = names[new Random().Next(0, names.Length)];
var sugRelevance = relevance[new Random().Next(0, relevance.Length)];
```

Write:

```
var sugName = names[random.Next(0, names.Length)];
var sugRelevance = relevance[random.Next(0, relevance.Length)];
```

Comment: thanks, solved my problem!